# Elasticsearch query to find range overlap

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have the following indexed document:

```
{
    "field1": [400, 800]
}
```

I want to create a query using 2 search parameters (`min_val = 300` and `max_val = 500`) to select documents where these two ranges overlaps.

In my example, the above document should be selected, as we can see:

```
300                    500
 [======================]
                   [=====================]
                  400                   800
```

What is the most efficient way to find documents that overlap two numeric ranges?
I can make it using multiple comparisons, and many *ands* and *ors*, but I'm looking for a simpler and efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: have you tried [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-range-query.html) filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES, a range of numbers like you have for `field1` is not actually a range but simply two distinct values, namely 400 and 800. All you have to do is to use a simple [`range` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-range-query.html) and compare `field1` with the lower and upper bound of the range, i.e.

- The range [300, 500] should include either 400 or 800

Expressed with the DSL, you end up with a single range query like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "field1": {
        "gte": 300,
        "lte": 500
      }
    }
  }
}
```